# Implement nivoslider and jqueryui.com/demos/dialog on one page

Tags: jquery-ui, nivo-slider

I want to implement Nivoslider for a slideshow as well as jQueryUI pop-op boxes. When I implement them as separate entities, then the pop-up boxes stop working as they should.

Is there a way to implement them together, or is there a fatal error?

By the way, I am a complete noob when it comes to js - please be kind and spell things out for me please :D

This is the code for Nivoslider:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
    effect: 'fade', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
    animSpeed: 2000, // Slide transition speed
    pauseTime: 6000, // How long each slide will show
    });
});
</script>
```

and this is the code for jQuery UI pop-up box:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My implementation based on the demo script provided with Nivo Slider, just add in jquery UI and use this code.  It stores the slider information and re-creates the slider each time the dialog is opened.

HTML Code

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <a href="http://dev7studios.com" id="dev7link" title="Go to dev7studios">dev7studios</a>

        <button id="btnTestMe">Open Slideshow</button>
    </div>

    <div id="dlgTestMe">
        <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                <img src="images/toystory.jpg" data-thumb="images/toystory.jpg" alt="" />
                <a href="http://dev7studios.com"><img src="images/up.jpg" data-thumb="images/up.jpg" alt="" title="This is an example of a caption" /></a>
                <img src="images/walle.jpg" data-thumb="images/walle.jpg" alt="" data-transition="slideInLeft" />
                <img src="images/nemo.jpg" data-thumb="images/nemo.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption" />
            </div>
            <div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">
                <strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a>. 
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

JQuery Code

```
$('#btnTestMe').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dlgTestMe').dialog({
        open: function(){
                var data = $('.slider-wrapper').html();
                if (typeof($(this).data("slider")) == "undefined"){
                    $(this).data("slider", data);
            }                   
            $('#slider').nivoSlider();
        }, beforeClose: function(){
            $('#slider, .nivo-controlNav, .nivo-html-caption').detach();
            $(this).children('.slider-wrapper').html($(this).data("slider"));
        }
    });     
});
```